# Right-align CSS sprite list

Tags: html, css

Please look at the Facebook/YouTube/Twitter icons at the top of http://live-fenfast.pantheonsite.io/. I'm trying to align them to the right like they are on http://fenfast.com. The difference on the "live-fenfast.pantheonsite.io" site is that I've converted plain img a hrefs with a styled list that uses CSS to reveal parts of a single image for clicking in the list (CSS sprites).

How do I right-align this list? I've tried a bunch of obvious CSS properties but none of them work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use bootstraps pull-right class

```
<ul id="socialnavlist" class="clearfix pull-right">
```

Comment: This worked best in my case because the list was already wrapped in a Bootstrap div.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use simply:

```
#socialnavlist {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
```

In my opinion you has a problems because you use:

```
#socialnavlist li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

This is a main reason of all your problems. If you use `position: absolute` you can't use normal align/float attributes, and you can't get what you need.